# How to configure engine ID to send SNMP trap V3 using SNMP4J？

Tags: net-snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap, snmptrapd

I'm using snmp4j 2.8.4 and Java 1.8

It works when I use the command line to send traps.for example

snmptrapd.conf

```
authCommunity   log,execute,net public
createUser -e 0x8000000001020304 myuser MD5 mypassword DES mypassword1
authUser log,execute,net myuser noauth
```

The command is

```
snmptrap -e 0x8000000001020304 -v 3 -u myuser  -a MD5 -A myjjpassword -x DES -X myjjpassword1 -l noAuthNoPriv 192.168.135.18:162 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.48183 1.3.6.1.4.1.48183.1 s "smartmon"
```

It was ok at this point, but when I used SNMP4J, I didn't know if my engine ID was not set up correctly, which caused the trap failure or some other reason

```
USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(), localEngineID, 0);

SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

usm.updateUser(new UsmUserEntry(new OctetString("myuser"),
  new OctetString("0x8000000001020304".getBytes()), new UsmUser(new OctetString("myuser"),
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null)));
snmp = new Snmp(transport);

snmp.setLocalEngine(new OctetString("0x8000000001020304".getBytes()).getValue(),0,0);

snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv3(usm));
transport.listen();
```

Could you tell me where I have a problem setting?How should I set the Engine ID?Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0):

OctetString uses a different string representation than NET-SNMP does. Thus, you need to specify your engine ID as:

OctetString.fromString("8000000001020304", 16);